# CSS media query not changing elements?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to get this media query to work...  I've changed a border and element colour, and position so I can clearly see when it's worked but it doesn't seem to be applying the rule at all - what have I missed?  I'm looking for spaces and typos but I can't see any...

HTML

```
<div id="introcontainer">
     <div id="introcontainer2">
         <div class="introbox" id="introbox1">48</div>
         <div class="introbox" id="introbox2">3</div>
         <div class="introbox" id="introbox3">£99</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)  and (max-width: 992px) {

#introcontainer {
    width: 660px; 
    height: 134px; 
    position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 100px; 
    margin-left: -330px; border-style: dashed; border-color: red;}

.introbox {
width: 214px;
height: 130px;
background: #fffff;
opacity: 0.1;
border-radius: 4px;}
}

#introcontainer {width: 660px; height: 134px; position: absolute; left: 50%;           top: 250px; margin-left: -330px; border-style: dashed; border-color: aqua;}

#introcontainer2 {position: relative;}
.introbox {
width: 214px;
height: 130px;
background: #6666CC;
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 4px;
}

#introbox1 {position: absolute; left: 0px;}

#introbox2 {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
#introbox3 {position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;}
```

Comment: If it helps, the website is at www.webtuu.com - if you move the browser below 768, the elements don't change as I've asked above.

Comment: For your info: .introbox background has 5 f, add one more or use 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there a chance that you forgot to close the @media?
because when I removed  the:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)  and (max-width: 992px) {
```

it worked.

you can see it in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ariel7342/pen/MyzQdq).
also maybe that your @media deceleration may be wrong ?

I think you should put it after your regular css, or change the min/max-width.

Comment: Looks like the reason is the positioning of my media query, didn't realise it should be after regular CSS, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things. 
First of all, `background:#fffff` in `.introbox` should be `#ffffff` or `#fff`.
Secondly, the rules in the `@media` rule are being overridden by the following rules outside of `@media`. That's all right, just move the `@media` rule so that it is at the end of the CSS rather than at the beginning. If you need anything else, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Put your media query CSS part **after** regular CSS declarations, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change an element's rules when the screen is < 992px you should use this code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:992px){...}
```

and try to avoid the range query like:

```
and (min-width: 768px)  and (max-width: 992px)
```

BUT you have to put it after the "normal" CSS.

See this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/605fz13p/1/)

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant < 992, not 768.  It looks like my error is not having it after regular CSS though, didn't realise that made a difference, thanks!

Comment: Oh ok, but the code work anyway :) (i'm going to update the answare)